# Formula to find amount of numbers that have at least 3 same symbols

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Example sequence → $111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888,999,1000,1011,1110,1111,1112,1113,\ldots$
Lets say I want to find the amount of numbers that fit this rule in the interval $(110;1102)$.
While the numbers are this low, I can calculate everything by hand (write every number down and count all the numbers that meet the criteria of having at least 3 same symbols in them). For this instance the numbers that fit the criteria are $111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888,999,1000,1011,1101$. The answer is $12$.

Is there a formula to calculate the amount of numbers that fit this criteria in a certain interval? Formula to calculate the next number quickly would help too.